# Extract feature file name from BDD cucumber java project

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, bdd

Problem: I am unable to extract the feature name of the current running feature file using below code -

------Code------

```
public String getFeatureName(){

    Object[] paramNames = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getParameters();
    String featureName = paramNames[1].toString().replaceAll("^\"+|\"+$", "");
    System.out.println("Feature file name: " + featureName);
    return featureName;
}
```

Its failing on first line of the above function with error as below -

Exception -

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> au.com.news.spp.pageobjects.LoginPage.getFeatureName(LoginPage.java:143)
> at au.com.news.spp.pageobjects.LoginPage.(LoginPage.java:57)
> at
> au.com.news.spp.steps.LoginPageStepDefinition.openLoginPage(LoginPageStepDefinition.java:24)
> at
> au.com.news.spp.steps.LoginPageStepDefinition.navigateAndLogin(LoginPageStepDefinition.java:32)
> at ✽.Given I login to
> Wordpress(/Users/a2264731/Documents/GitHub/spp-test-automation/src/test/resources/features/TemplateEndpointFunction/Validation.feature:5)

When I debugged the code, it gets into InvocationTargetException.java

I just added this code with testng dependency in pom.xml. Later executed this code but facing null pointer issue. Could you guys please help me in getting feature name here using above code?

Comment: There's not enough information.  What code is putting the featurename in the Parameters? Give information about the cucumber setup, how is the framework structured.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hooks to get the feature name before it get started.

```
public class Hooks {
    
    @Before
    public void getFeatureName(Scenario scenario) {
        System.out.println(scenario.getName()); //Prints feature name
        System.out.println(scenario.getUri()); //Prints feature file location
    }

}
```